# How to continue a recording?

Tags: sox

How can I continue an existing wav recording using SOX ?

I tried with:
rec test.wav --combine concatenate test2.wav

test.wav is the old file
test2.wav is the new file

The problem is that the new recording is placed at start instead that at end of test.wav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rec` command is just a shortcut for `sox -d` where `-d` can be used in place of an input or output file to select the default device as input or output. When you write

```
rec test.wav --combine concatenate test2.wav
```

it will be the same as

```
sox -d test.wav --combine concatenate test2.wav
```

in this case `-d` is listed before `test.wav` and thus will be the first part of the output file. Running

```
sox test.wav -d --combine concatenate test2.wav
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked very well!! can you share your email address ?

Comment: and what if I would like to continue recording the same file?